# useCallback with onchange function in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 components. In the parent component I have this:

```
const Demo = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  const onChange = useCallback(
    (value: string) => {
      console.log(value);
    },
    [],
  );

  return (
    <div className="a">
      <button onClick={() => setState(!state)}>sds</button>
      <div className="123">
        <Bar searchHandler={onChangeSearchHandler} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the `Bar` component I have this:

```
const Bar = ({ searchHandler }) => {
    console.log('bar');
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(value) => searchHandler(value.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Wrapping `onChange` with `useCallback` I expect to cache the function and when I click on `<button onClick={() => setState(false)}>sds</button>` I don't want to  render `Bar` component, but it is triggered. Why `Bar` component is triggered and how to prevent this with `useCallback`?

Comment: With `useCallback` the function instance stays the same, that is correct, but you cannot assume that the render function of subcomponents is not run again. However you can wrap your subcomponent in `React.memo`. But you still do not have a guarantee that the render function is not called. But seriously: don't try to optimiz how often the render function is called.

Comment: By the way: I think you have a typo with `onChangeSearchHandler` vs `onChange`

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the `onChange` function you're wrapping with `useCallback`. `Bar` gets re-rendered because you're changing the state through `setState` in its parent component. When you change the state in a component all its child components get re-rendered.

You can verify it yourself by trying this:

```
const Demo = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="a">
      <button onClick={() => setState(!state)}>sds</button>
      <div className="123">
        <Bar />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const Bar = ({ searchHandler }) => {
  console.log('bar');

  return (
    <div></div>
  );
};
```

You'll see that the `Bar` gets re-rerender anyway.

If you want to skip re-rerendring any of the child components, you should memoize them using [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) when applicable.

Also, you should familiarize yourself with how state in react works and how does it affect the nested components as this is a **main concept**.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you haven't used `React.memo` on Bar component. The function `useCallback` works only if you use HOC from memo.

try this, in Bar component create this wrapped component:

```
const WrappedBar = React.memo(Bar);
```

and in parent component use this wrapped bar:

```
const Demo = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  const onChange = useCallback(
    (value: string) => {
      console.log(value);
    },
    [],
  );

  return (
    <div className="a">
      <button onClick={() => setState(!state)}>sds</button>
      <div className="123">
        <WrappedBar searchHandler={onChangeSearchHandler} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```